# How to set multiple aws credentials in nodejs aws-sdk module?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I need to use multiple AWS credentials for different services like s3, SNS....

```
var awsS3 = require('aws-sdk');
var awsSes = require('aws-sdk');

awsS3.config.update({
    region: config.awsRegion,
    accessKeyId: config.sesAccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: config.sesSecretAccessKey
});

awsSes.config.update({
    region: config.s3Region,
    accessKeyId: config.s3AccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: config.s3SecretAccessKey
  });
```

But above code is not working.

How to configure multiple accessKeyIds, secretAccessKeys for different services?

Comment: have you tried something like

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ /* credentials for s3*/ });
const ses = new aws.SES({ /* credentials for ses*/ });

I'm not sure if this works but I can't try it myself atm.

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass config while creating service objects. Following is what you are looking for

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({ /* s3 config */ });
const ses = new aws.SES({ /* ses config */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think you want to control it with policies instead of having multiple credentials.  Use a single credentials/role, then custom policies on what you want to allows and deny for each service.  Then your application can use that role/credentials and will be allows or restricted base on the policies.